# How to convert a Win2003 server to a Hyper-V Virtual Machine?

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, hyper-v, physical-to-virtual

What is the easiest way to convert a Win2003 server to a Hyper-V Virtual machine?

Ideally, I'd like to use a backup tool to create an image across the network.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft SysInternals has a utility, Disk2Vhd, which will do this for you.  You can run this on a live machine, and it can create a VHD file to an external location, such as a network drive.  You can then copy this VHD to where it needs to live on the Hyper-V host, and create a new VM guest using that file.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Disk2Vhd works great as a one-off tool (you may have to do some manual fixup to the HAL to get it to boot after converting the physical server to a VHD).  If you are looking to do this in an enterprise environment (perhaps P2V-ing and managing multiple virtual servers) you would want to take a look at [System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/virtualmachinemanager/en/us/default.aspx) (that's a mouthful!)

Answer (score 0):

Tried disk2vhd, v2+ and ran into the 7b BSOD crashing. Found Xenconvert was much simpler:
http://www.citrix.com/go/products/xenserver/xenserver-xenconvert-free.html#top

Still have to reactivate windows though.